# exclude test.js file in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have used create-react-app to create an application.

I have my `.test.js` files next to the files they are testing:

so:

```
|
|_ Input.js
|_ Input.test.js
```

Do I need to add anything to `.babelrc` to stop the `*.test.js` files getting bundled with the development or production build.

I can't see anywhere in the source where they are being excluded.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to do it:
create config-override.js in your root folder
then add this

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
// Exclude .test.ts files from the build
config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map(rule => {
    if (rule.oneOf) {
        rule.oneOf = rule.oneOf.map(oneOfRule => {
            if (oneOfRule.test && oneOfRule.test.toString() === 
                '/\\.test\\.js$/') {
                // Exclude .test.ts files
                oneOfRule.exclude = /\.test\.ts$/;
                }
            return oneOfRule;
            });
        }
        return rule;
      });

      return config;
  };
```

---

This code modifies the webpack configuration by excluding .test.ts files from the build process.

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude the test by changing the expression for the files included for build in webpack-config.js

```
/^(?!.*\.test\.js$).*\.js$/
```

This will load only '.js' files while leaving 'test.js' files

Comment: Could you please clarify ?
I have create-react-app with dotenv 5.0.1 and npm run works fine, but npm build fails because it's file is ES6. So how to add that to ignore list in packing it, but it's still needed in pre-compiling the project

Comment: i dont think `weboack-config.js` is available to non-ejected apps created with create-react-app